# Is it healthy to share our job opportunities with current colleagues?

Tags: career-development, work-environment, colleagues

I planned to move for better opportunity. iIn this case is it good for me to share this information with my colleagues? because all my colleagues were close to me. Of course, they are all different character. We dont know what they will think and too i don't know whether it will spoil my future career or current employer relation..

Comment: As you pointed out, they are all different characters and we don't know what they or others will think. So it'll be hard to give you a correct answer to whether this will spoil your (current and future) relations.

Comment: @CMW Absolutely, we cannot expect same response from all of our friends, one may encourage, one may discourage. That is why i mentioned that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the etiquette around discussing interview for new positions with my current coworkers?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1121/what-is-the-etiquette-around-discussing-interview-for-new-positions-with-my-curr)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would not share this with any of your colleagues until it has come to pass. Even very good friends can get jealous of you becoming better than them, even though this may not be the way you think. I like to think of the tall poppy syndrome where there is always someone waiting to cut it down! After you have your new position and you talk with your colleagues, you will soon know who are true friends and those that would of tried stopping you advance.