# What is the etiquette of discussing new contracts with current team, as a contractor?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, job-search, colleagues, united-states

There’s a related question here: [What is the etiquette around discussing interview for new positions with my current coworkers?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1121/40440)

The other question seems geared toward full-time. My question is specifically about discussing potential new contracts/gigs with co-workers while it’s known that you are a contractor/freelancer.

The context here is everyone is aware that you are a contractor and that many people come in and out as a contractors. Some may work as short as a 4 weeks; some may work 6 months or more.

The question is not about openly discussing other roles, but what to do if asked or it happens to come up.

Comment: Always just err on the side of caution.  It's work - be totally professional and low-key.  Often you can deflect the issue by saying "Hey, I'm just a contractor here!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally, don't wish to talk about my other contracts and I don't wish to be asked about them.  Even if I have a great working relationship at the company I work with.

How I manage my business is really no one else's business. If was asked this question. I would respond;

***When you ask this question for what purpose?*** (this put the onus responsibility BACK to the person who asked the question...its clever and totally unexpected.)

***I would say to them that type of question is very inappropriate and I am very uncomfortable having this discussion with you about this. I mean no disrespect, I will not have this discussion. Thank you.***

Then walk away from the conversation make a cup of coffee/Tea

Comment: First time around, I'd probably try to leave of the second sentence.  Second time around, I wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the values of the organisation you are currently contracting for.
Some companies are more open than others.
If you are not familiar with the current client, I would avoid commenting on other opportunities.
If you are familiar, and look forward being seeing a reliable, available resource,I would avoid commenting on other opportunities.

If you are familiar and comfortable with your client, I would only discuss on your other opportunities in situations where there is a real opportunity cost in not getting the advice of your clients' employees.

Comment: So if you are not familiar, avoid commenting. If you are familiar, and want repeat jobs, avoid commenting. And only discuss in limited circumstances?

Comment: I think that would be the optimal way forward. Many clients would appreciate feeling there is nothing else but their priorities in your mind. If you want to break this illusion, there should be a good reason.

Comment: "Many clients would appreciate feeling there is nothing else but their priorities in your mind." This is a good point to remember always. :)